# Swift & Parse - Am trying to retrieve a username with a query.

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfuser

I am trying to retrieve the username belonging to a post. The username can be found in another class however.

These are the two classes I have:
[Post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zARk.png)
[User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDAZU.png)

I am populating all the information from the Posts class in a UICollectionView but since the username is in the User class my query is not working. Here's my code...

```
 //QUERY LOST

    let querylost = PFQuery(className: "Post")
    querylost.order(byDescending: "createdAt")
    querylost.whereKey("lostfound", equalTo: "lost")
    querylost.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in

        if let posts = objects {

            for post in posts {


                self.addresslost.append(post["address"] as! String)

                self.breedlost.append(post["breed"] as! String)

                self.phonelost.append(post["phone"] as! String)

                self.imageFileslost.append(post["imageFile"] as! PFFile)

                //HERE'S THE PROBLEM - username is in User Class

                self.usernames.append(self.queryusers[post["userid"] as! String]!)

                //ENDS here

                self.lostCollectionView.reloadData()

                self.refresherLost.endRefreshing()


            }
        }
    }

    //TO SHOW DATA

    scrollView.delegate = self
    lostCollectionView.delegate = self
    lostCollectionView.dataSource = self

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `userid` field, you should create a pointer to put on your Post object instead. Then you can access the User object via the Post object.

Your code would look something like this:

```
let querylost = PFQuery(className: "Post")
querylost.order(byDescending: "createdAt")
querylost.include("user")
querylost.whereKey("lostfound", equalTo: "lost")
querylost.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in

    if let posts = objects {

        for post in posts {


            self.addresslost.append(post["address"] as! String)

            self.breedlost.append(post["breed"] as! String)

            self.phonelost.append(post["phone"] as! String)

            self.imageFileslost.append(post["imageFile"] as! PFFile)

            //unwrap the user pointer, and get the username
            if let user = post["user"] as? PFUser, let username = user.username{
                self.usernames.append(username) 
            }

            //ENDS here

            self.lostCollectionView.reloadData()

            self.refresherLost.endRefreshing()


        }
    }
}
```